# "cust" process on Mac with very high CPU usage drains battery in 30 minutes

Tags: macos, mac

The battery of my Macbook Air High Sierra goes down very fast, something is definitely wrong.

I checked Activity Monitor and identified a process named `cust` that is using 200-300% of CPU:

[image]

1. Does anyone know what `cust` is?
2. Would a process using so much CPU cause battery to drain in 30 minutes?

---

Edit:

This is the output of `ps -ef | grep cust`:

[image]

This is the output of `find / -name cust -type f 2>/dev/null`:

[image]

Comment: Never heard of it, could you add a screenshot of Activity Monitor showing `cust`? Could you launch Terminal and add to your question the output of command `ps -ef | grep cust`?

Comment: I added the screenshots

Comment: Thank you for adding the screenshot and running the command. The next step would be to find out where `cust` resides in the file system. Could you open Terminal and run these command `find / -name cust -type f 2>/dev/null` (the search may take a while, be patient)? This should output all files on your Mac named `cust`. There aren't hopefully many... could you add the output to your answer?

Comment: I've attached screen shot with results of terminal command.  Looks like it is coming from something called Bask Client.  I'll need to do some Googling on that.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you found the culprit. I've found some information about BASK Client here: https://www.shouldiremoveit.com/BASK-Client-202550-program.aspx. Is this a work computer? In this case, contact your help desk. If it isn't, you could rename the folder with this command: `sudo mv /usr/local/BASK /usr/local/BASK-backup` (`sudo` let's you run the `mv` command as administrator, you will have to type your password when requested) Reboot after renaming it and let's hope the issue is gone.

Comment: @Jaume Success!!!!!  Thank you for help figuring this out.  The cust process is no longer running and that out of control process was responsible for crushing the battery.  Laptop now has normal battery life.

Comment: Great news, I'm happy the issue is solved! Could you please add an answer describing the steps to solve the issue? You can then mark your answer as accepted and collect the reputation, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer for details.